# How to handle an expression when input is taken from a csv

Tags: csv, format, export, expression

Beginner with powershell and looking for some help with the @{Label='ID'; expression={??} section please:-

```
$ID = @()
Import-Csv C:\computers2.csv | ForEach-Object {$ID += $_.ID}
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ID | 
Select-Object -Property DeviceID, @{Label='ID'; expression= 
{$ID}},
@{Label='Total (Gb)'; expression={($_.Size/1GB).ToString('F2')}},
@{Label='Free (Gb)'; expression= 
{($_.FreeSpace/1GB).ToString('F2')}},
@{label='Percent'; expression={[Math]::Round(($_.freespace / 
$_.size) * 100, 2)}} | Format-Table
```

The output I get is this:-

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkEgy.png)

What I'm trying to achieve would be this:-

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwm08.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out after following some guides and getting the correct variables

```
$CSV = Import-Csv C:\computers.csv
$SPACE = ForEach ($ID in $CSV) {
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName ($ID.ID) | 
Select-Object -Property DeviceID,
@{Label='ID'; expression={$_.SystemName}},
@{Label='Total (Gb)'; expression={($_.Size/1GB).ToString('F2')}},
@{Label='Free (Gb)'; expression={($_.FreeSpace/1GB).ToString('F2')}},
@{Label='PercentFree'; expression={[Math]::Round(($_.freespace / $_.size) * 
100, 2)}}
} | FormatTable
```